# Need to provide separate output for empty element tag and content element tag of same element using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I'm having the "text" tag for separate parent tag, in that some times for that text tag content will be empty, that time i want that tag with separate output and content element "text" needs to be in separate tags:

My Input XML is:

```
<introText>
<text/>
</introText>
<directionText>
<text>CLICK ON EACH CATEGORY TO GET STARTED, AND WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED, EVALUATE YOUR LISTS. WHICH LIST IS LONGER?</text>
</directionText>
```

XSL I used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:json="http://json.org/" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:template match="introText">
        "introText": {
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        },
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="directionText">
        "directionText": {
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="100"/>

    <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="concat('((.{1,', $length, '})( |$))')"/>

    <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' +&#10; '"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), ' ', '&quot;')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        "text": <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space(string-join(node()/serialize(., $ser-params), '')))"/>,
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My getting the output as:

```
introText: {

    "text": ""

    },

    directionText: {

    "text": "CLICK ON EACH CATEGORY TO GET STARTED, AND WHEN YOU ARE" + 
"FINISHED, EVALUATE YOUR LISTS. WHICH LIST IS LONGER?",

    }
```

But i want the empty element "text" have to be like below output file

Expected Output file:

```
introText: {

    "text":' "" '

    },

    directionText: {

    "text": "CLICK ON EACH CATEGORY TO GET STARTED, AND WHEN YOU ARE" + 
"FINISHED, EVALUATE YOUR LISTS. WHICH LIST IS LONGER?",

    }
```

The extra single quote need to cover that double quotes if that text is empty, Likewise lot of "text" tag coming in article, So i want to write the XSL for "text" template alone. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle an empty `text` element separately, simply add a new template to match such an element, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="text[not(normalize-space())]">
    "text": ' "" ',
</xsl:template>
```

The `normalize-space()` will mean it will also pick up `text` nodes that contain nothing but whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @TimC. Its working. Eg, for all the empty element of single article needs to be like above with ' "" ' quotes means. How i can mention in XSL for the value with element. Please tell me

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you expand your question if there are other situations you need to cover? Thanks!

Comment: Ok Sure @TimC, I will ask this as new question on future. Now for this, its working fine. Thanks!!